# Ubuntu server has no access to internet

Tags: networking, server, ssh

On my Ubuntu Server 16.04(it is a virtual machine), after I set the IP to static as follows:

```
# The primary network interface
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
  address 192.168.70.10
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.70.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I have no access to the internet. The following ping does not work:

```
dockerize@containerize:~$ ping www.google.ch
ping: unknown host www.google.ch
```

Then I set back to DHCP, the ping works:

```
dockerize@containerize:~$ ping www.google.ch
PING www.google.ch (216.58.213.195) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ham02s15-in-f195.1e100.net (216.58.213.195): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=29.8 ms
64 bytes from ham02s15-in-f195.1e100.net (216.58.213.195): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=30.1 ms
^C
--- www.google.ch ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 29.882/30.001/30.121/0.210 ms
```

I've got following IP from DHCP:

```
dockerize@containerize:~$ ifconfig
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:bf:cf:78  
          inet addr:192.168.70.135  Bcast:192.168.70.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:febf:cf78/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:230 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:111 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22864 (22.8 KB)  TX bytes:14513 (14.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)
```

I can access the server via ssh. What is wrong?

**Update**

Network information with DHCP:

```
dockerize@containerize:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.70.2
search localdomain

dockerize@containerize:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.70.2 dev ens33 
192.168.70.0/24 dev ens33  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.70.135
```

Then I change interfaces to:

```
# The primary network interface
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.70.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.70.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.70.2
```

Comment: What output does poing produce?

Comment: Nothing. Just empty line.

Comment: That doesn't seem possible. If ping failed, it should give an error message. Please [edit] your question and clarify that. Also explain how you access the server via ssh. Is it over a local area connection, or are you connecting over the internet? If you can connect over the internet through `ssh`, the machine is obviously connected to the internet and the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: When connected via DHCP - which DNS servers do you get (`cat /etc/resolv.conf`) and what is the route you get (`ip route`)? Is it possible outgoing DNS probes are blocked? Try using the same DNS as handed per DHCP.

Comment: I've got DNS server `nameserver 192.168.70.2`.

Comment: should I write `nameserver` or `dns-nameservers`.

Comment: iproute says: `default via 192.168.70.2 dev ens33 
192.168.70.0/24 dev ens33  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.70.135 
`

Comment: I updated my post again. Please consider Network information.

Comment: OK, so it's a DNS issue. Just to confirm, when you're using the static address, you can `ping 8.8.8.8` right? It's only when using domain names that it fails?

Comment: The default gateway when using DHCP is `192.168.70.2`. If you change the `gateway` line in your static config to that address it should work.

Comment: and the `DNS`, what for `IP` should I assign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you provided based on terdons questions I conclude the following problem:

You expected the default gateway to be `192.168.70.1` when it actually is available at `192.168.70.2`.

To fix this, try the following configuration for `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The primary network interface
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.70.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.70.2
dns-nameservers 192.168.70.2
```

Note: You could still use google's DNS IPs for the values in `dns-nameservers`. If you want to do so, use the following configuration:

```
# The primary network interface
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.70.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.70.2
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```